# shell scripting EXPR syntax error

Tags: shell, scripting, sh

I am getting a syntax error in the following code.
I am trying to print the squares of a number n.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter a number n to print squares : "
read num

i=1

while [ $i -le $num ]
do

    echo $(expr $i * $i)
    i=$(expr $i + 1)

done

echo "Done with Script"
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong with the code?
Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code. Is that all you want to tell us?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter a number n to print squares : "
read num

i=1

while [ $i -le $num ]
do

    echo $(expr $i \* $i)
    i=$(expr $i + 1)

done

echo "Done with Script"
```

Shield `*` symbol.

Comment: Would you like to give more explanation? Why is it necessary to escape/shield the asterisk?

Comment: Because it's a wildcard character to the shell. Equivalently, quote it. Better yet, don't use `expr` (and don't tag questions as [tag:bash] if they are not about Bash at all; but if you do have access to Bash, that's a good way to avoid `expr` completely).

Comment: Yes Why do we need to shield '*' ?

Comment: @tripleee What are the alternatives of expr?

Comment: You posted this question with the tags [tag:bash] and [tag:linux] so I assume you have Bash. Read the man page, look for "arithmetic".

Comment: @AbhishekGangadhar you can write `i=$(($i + 1))`; `echo $(($i * $i))`

Comment: @ViktorKhilin Thank you :)